# Reverse CreateObject in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, createobject

I have an old vbscript the runs the command, foo = CreateObject(x.y). I want to run this script on another computer (which it doesn't run on now btw) but I don't know which dll's I should register, or what else I should do, to run the CreateObject command.

How can I figure out what dll's I need to copy into the new computer, and do I need to register them, what else should be done?

Or maybe they are OCX's or something?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start looking at your machine registry for your `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\x.y\CLSID` key.

With that `{GUID}`, go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\InprocServer32` key

Comment: That's how create object is implemented? Cool.

Comment: Found it, so now i just export all the registry settings and the dll's and copy them over to the other computer?

Comment: you'll need also to register that component with `regsvr32`

Comment: You should not need to export registry settings, copy the DLL and register it as per Rubens Farias' comment.

Comment: Of course it might not be as simply as that.  The dll found in the InprocServer32 may itself also have dependancies on other COM library files and standard dlls.